# Editing searchable .pdf OCR

Tags: pdf, text-editing, ocr, scanning, document-scanning

My case is quite specific so I'll try to explain it quickly and precisely.
I have to digitalize several old paper sheets of 230mm x 268mm (~ 9" x 27,7")  folded in 4 parts; you can find a quick drawn example [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ygbtt.jpg) to get an idea.

The scanning and recomposition is not quite the real issue, I'll scan every fold and put it together via photoshop. What I need is a .pdf file with the original scanned page image, and also with the text readable/searchable and indexable for web search engines.
As you can see in the draw above linked, on the page there are also few ADS box, which I don't really need to be OCR'd, and can be left out.

Now I've used Acrobat Pro X on the resulting .pdf file I recomposed via Photoshop. The results are quite good, but not perfect of course, and what I find most problematic is to correct wrong elaborated text and delete or exclude non necessary area of the document.

What I'd like to know is if there is an application for editing underlying OCR text in a more practical way than what Acrobat offers. Adobe gives in the tool pannel a "Find suspects" (which can be really annoying to use), but the suspected text is not always complete with what really is wrong, many times characters it recognise as correct are not at all (ex. italic "l" are considered "/", and similar); unfortunately my text is partially composed of other languages fonts also, like japanese or chinese, and the text turns most of the times as crappy jibberish, so I also need to fix the wrong text accordingly to the selectable characters.

A sort of compared editor, like in one pane the scanned image, in the other the OCR text of a selected area of the document, would be the most ideal solution, I think, to correct quickly and efficiently the errors.
Possibilities to define and exclude areas of the scanned document to be processed by the OCR would be another very needed function indeed; I've found that with Acrobat you can use the direct arrow edit tool to remove text frames, which can be sort of functional, even tho quite hard to use since you will most of the time click on the background scanned image..

Any suggestion for this type of work? Maybe another workflow more practical and/or efficient? Any tips are welcome indeed!

Im on a Win 7 64 bit machine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might try [ABBYY FineReader](http://finereader.abbyy.com/professional/). It fits the description of your needs.

Comment: Where can this be found?

Comment: I just added the link. It is not free software.

Comment: It is indeed a very valid program, with exactely what I asked. It's a bit overwhelming in the beginning, but the online documentation is very complete and quite intuitive for some simple actions!