# Edit OCR metadata in a PDF file

Tags: windows, pdf

I have various PDF Files which contain PDF-Text (from OCR) stored in metadata.
Sometimes/Often the OCR is not quite accurate, so I would like to **EDIT** the metadata. I use `pdftotext` to extract this metadata, though I can't find a simple way to overwrite/edit the text in a PDF file.

I am looking for the simplest solution to edit/overwrite the metadata. (Freeware/Commandline)

Comment: I find the title should rather be "Edit metadata in a PDF file", don't it?

Comment: @duDE You are right. I will edit it now.

Comment: But [notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/) eventually with [hex plugin](http://sourceforge.net/projects/npp-plugins/files/Hex%20Editor/), or another of the _plugin_ [suggested here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14617888/3569208) couldn't work for you? ps> you can get the code too.

Comment: If you have java installed you can try [PDF Metadata Editor](http://zaro.github.io/pdf-metadata-editor/)... [source code](https://github.com/zaro/pdf-metadata-editor) available too...

Comment: The OCR text layer isn't "metadata". For more relevant answers see https://superuser.com/questions/717371/editing-searchable-pdf-ocr and https://superuser.com/questions/141628/good-free-ocr-with-gui-for-correcting-mistakes-for-windows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### How do I edit PDF metadata?

Try [AutoMetadata](http://www.evermap.com/autometadata.asp) (free for both commercial and non-commercial use)

> AutoMetadata™ is a free standalone application for exploring and editing metadata, document properties and viewer preferences in multiple PDF documents.
>
> The key feature is ability to select many PDF files and folders and quickly inspect and update information in all documents with a minimal effort.

...

> Not to mention that this software is free for both commercial and non-commercial use.
>
> [image]
>
> **Editing Document Metadata**
>
> You can either edit metadata in place or perform a search and replace operation on selected fields. Use this operation to update multiple PDF documents with a common metadata change.

Source [AutoMetadata](http://www.evermap.com/autometadata.asp)

---

#### Disclaimer

I am not affiliated with [AutoMetadata](http://www.evermap.com/autometadata.asp)
in any way.

Comment: >I am not affiliated with AutoMetadata in any way. Anyone can say that ;)

Comment: @duDE I just like to make it clear when I recommend software. Then I can't be accused of self-promotion or spamming ;)

Comment: I have tried this software with no luck. It can't even extract the text. Thank you for the answer though.

Comment: @BenjaminWeiss It works fine here. I don't have any PDFs with OCR scanned metadata to test with though.